QuTiP tutorial: How to derive the analytical solution to the expectation value of an operator for a system evolving by Lindbladian
I am following the simple tutorial below:
(https://nbviewer.org/urls/qutip.org/qutip-tutorials/tutorials-v5/time-evolution/003_qubit-dynamics.ipynb)
In this they look at single qubit with Hamiltonian $H = \frac{\Delta}{2}\sigma_{x}$ and 1 jump operator $c = \sqrt{g}\sigma_{z}$.
The Lidbladian ME for such a system will be:
$$
\dot \rho = -i[\frac{\Delta}{2}\sigma_{x}, \rho] + g(\sigma_{z}\rho\sigma_{z} - \rho).
$$
I try to find the equation of motion for $\sigma_{z}$ by using the following
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\langle \sigma_z \rangle = \mathrm{Tr}[\sigma_{z}\dot\rho]
$$
and then substituting the above equation. This leads to the two coupled differential equations
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\langle \sigma_{z} \rangle = \Delta \langle \sigma_y \rangle
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\langle \sigma_{y} \rangle = - (\Delta \langle \sigma_z \rangle + 2g\langle \sigma_y \rangle).
$$
I try to solve these in the standard way by converting it to a matrix-vector equation and finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors etc. However, I do not get remotely close to the analytical solution which they write as
$$
\langle \sigma_{z} \rangle = cos(2\pi t)e^{-gt}.
$$
Is it possible to get this same analytical solution this way? And if so how?
